# How can I close a Bootstrap Collapse using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I want to be able to close or open a collapse using javasript. Any idea?

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
<!--Something else here-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("element-selector").collapse('hide')
$("element-selector").collapse('toggle')
$("element-selector").collapse('show')
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#methods

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="searchBar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filters">
    Search
</div>
<div id="filters" class="collapse row">
  Hello
</div>

document.getElementById("searchBar").classList.toggle("collapsed");
document.getElementById("filters").classList.remove("in");
```